# Is it possible to browse a structure?

Tags: c++, structure

I need to fill a structure every 10 mS, in this strucure there are 230 variables, only `bool` and `int`. My thinking was first to fill and intialize randomly one by one all the variable. But it's very long to write and seems like very ugly code. Also this structure change often.

So my second thinking was to browse the structure ( maybe using a loop ? ) and fill randomly every variable.

After some research, I can't find anything. So, Is there a way to browse my structure and to fill the variable randomly ?

Thank you for your help.

EDIT : Here's what I try to do :

I've got a header file containing the structure :

```
    typedef struct
        {
            /// Statut Ground-Flight
            int _statutGroundFlight;
            /// Statut Capteur de presence
            bool _statutCapteurPrensence;
            /// Statut Bouton OPEN in
            bool _statutBoutonOpenIn;
            /// Statut Bouton OPEN ext
            bool _statutBoutonOpenExt;
            /// Statut Bouton CLOSE in
            bool _statutBoutonCloseIn;
            /// Statut Bouton CLOSE ext
            bool _statutBoutonCloseExt;
...
```

And here's what I want to do every 10 mS:

```
//Create a structure
struct myStruct;

//Browse the structure
for(int i; myStruct.size(); ++i){
   if(myStruct[i] is int){
      //Fill it randomly with int
   }
   if(mystruct[i] is bool){
      //Fill it randomly with bool
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to initialize the structure? It is unclear from your question what you want to do.

Comment: 1° It's quite strange to have a structure with 230 fields which change "often". 2° Can't you just create a structure as in `struct myStructType myVar` and leave it uninitialized (if it's only `bool` and `int`, I think that should do it)

Comment: @HAL Yes, this is what i want, i edit right now, sorry.

Comment: Fill randomly? By default c++ does not initialize variables, which means w/e was is left in memory stays in there (That's pretty much random).

Comment: This doesn't make any sense to me but still.. what should this structure do?

Comment: @EvansBelloeil May be some code here will put your question into context.

Comment: @MarcoA. This structure should contains variable, then i can read it and print it on screen, i will repeat this action every 10 ms.

Comment: @EvansBelloeil all right, why the random values to initialize them?

Comment: @HAL Well, i've only got the structure's code and this is a basic structure.

Comment: Why don't use std::map to hold the structure data? You would have easier time iterating over each element.

Comment: I suggest you edit the question and show a small code sample of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @LukaszDaniluk This is not stupid at all, but if I could do it without change the structure form, because I work in a society and i'm not the one that create the structure. But your solution look interesting, and can maybe solve my problem.

Comment: @atoMerz: That is a terrible comment. Reading an uninitialized value has undefined behaviour!

Comment: Also, you could try to do something like that: `MyStructure * p = &myStructure; char * pc = ( char * ) p; for( size_t i=0; i<sizeof( MyStructure ); ++i ) *(pc+i) = RANDOM_BYTE; ` if you are worried about not changing lots of code.

Comment: @EvansBelloeil: I think you're asking for some kind of *reflection*, but not the good kind. There's work going on on reflection, but I doubt that that's a good way to solve your problem. You probably shouldn't have a struct with 100+ member declarations... You don't by any chance have members like `enemy1`, `enemy2`, ..., `enemy15 /* TODO: support more enemies */`, `weapon1, `weapon2`...?

Comment: What are you doing with the data? Why does it need to be random? I feel that if the data is random, you don't need to store it in a struct at all. Just use random values at the point of displaying it in your UI.

Comment: @tenfour the data is random only for a test, in the future this will not be random at all. But for my test right now, this need to be random.

Comment: Write a function to do it.  Yes, the function will be ugly, but you only have to do it once per struct.  That also allows you to set limits on how random the data is.  I do think you might consider a different design, such as an array with an enum to describe the order of fields which would allow you to iterate if you needed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to browse the structure and fill the variables as you want, but you can avoid writing codes by using macro. 
You can write macro and let the pre-processor to generate the code for you .. 
for example:

create one struct.def where you can define required fields

```
#ifndef INTEGER
#error "INTEGER not defined"
#endif
#ifndef BOOL
#error "BOOL not defined"
#endif  
#ifndef create_struct 
#error "create_struct not defined"
#endif  


create_struct(my_struct,
        INTEGER(i1)
        BOOL(b1,false)
        INTEGER(i2)
        INTEGER(i3)
        BOOL(b2,true)
        BOOL(b3,false)
        BOOL(b4,false)
        INTEGER(i4)
        //add or modify fields here
)       

#undef INTEGER
#undef BOOL
#undef create_struct
```

Then write macro in your code by using above file

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"
//create structure
#define INTEGER(var_name) int var_name;
#define BOOL(var_name,data) bool var_name;
#define create_struct(struct_id,data_type)\
        typedef struct struct_id##_tag{\
                data_type\
        }struct_id;
#include "struct.def"
//-------------------------------------------

//function to initialize default value
#define INTEGER(var_name) p->var_name=0;
#define BOOL(var_name,data) p->var_name=data;
#define create_struct(struct_id,data_type)\
        void initialize_##struct_id(struct_id* p)\
        {\
                data_type\
        }
#include "struct.def"
//-------------------------------------------------

//function to fill random value to structure        
#define INTEGER(var_name) p->var_name=rand();
#define BOOL(var_name,data) p->var_name=rand()%2;
#define create_struct(struct_id,data_type)\
        void fill_random_##struct_id(struct_id* p)\
        {\
                data_type\
        }
#include "struct.def"
//-----------------------------------------
```

Now if you run preprocessor then it will generate the below mentioned code for you....

```
typedef struct my_struct_tag{
        int i1;
        bool b1; 
        int i2; 
        int i3;
        bool b2; 
        bool b3; 
        bool b4; 
        int i4; 
}my_struct;
void initialize_my_struct(my_struct* p) { 
        p->i1=0; 
        p->b1=false; 
        p->i2=0;
        p->i3=0; 
        p->b2=true;
        p->b3=false; 
        p->b4=false;
        p->i4=0; 
}
void fill_random_my_struct(my_struct* p) {
        p->i1=rand(); 
        p->b1=rand()%2;
        p->i2=rand(); 
        p->i3=rand(); 
        p->b2=rand()%2;
        p->b3=rand()%2;
        p->b4=rand()%2; 
        p->i4=rand();
}
```

Now, if you want to change your structure then you need to change in only one place that is in `struct.def` file

You can check the link http://rajenpandit.blogspot.in/p/using-macro.html for further details.

Answer (score 1):

I would opt to use `std::map` to store values of your members.

```
class MyStructure
{
    std::map< unsigned int, int > integerValues;
    std::map< unsigned int, bool > booleanValues;
public:
    bool & exampleBoolean = booleanValues[ 0 ];
    int & exampleInteger = integerValues[ 0 ];
    void randomIntegers() { 
        for( auto & integer : integerValues )
            integer.second = randomInteger(); // put your favorite random here
    }
};
```

This way you will change only the place data is actually stored, not the way that you have accessed your structure.

I would recommend making `enum` with field names to index a map.

Answer (score 1):

An easy approach is to group the same-type fields, then create a union with type-specific arrays.

Example at [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/ALjBUi)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

union X
{
    struct
    {
        int i1, i2, i3;
        bool b1, b2, b3;
    };

    struct
    {
        int is[3];
        bool bs[3];
    };
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const X& x)
{
    os << "{ ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        os << x.is[i] << ' ' << x.bs[i] << ' ';
    return os << '}';
}

int main()
 {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        X x;
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
        {
            x.is[j] = rand();
            x.bs[j] = rand() % 2;
        }
        std::cout << x << '\n';
    }
}
```

(Of course you should do something better than hard-coding the array dimensions wherever it's indexed, and allow the number of `int`s and `bool`s to vary independently, but that's all trivial....)

Sample output:

```
{ 1804289383 0 1681692777 1 1957747793 1 }
{ 719885386 0 596516649 1 1025202362 1 }
{ 783368690 1 2044897763 0 1365180540 0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot iterate over fields of a structure like you want.

If this is for a test, then you should not adapt the structure to suit the test. Instead, just do it the "hard" way - filling each field. This is also important because different fields certainly have different ways of being "random". For example `_statutGroundFlight` probably cannot be ANY integer value; it probably has a set of valid values to test.